# When I'm looking at a commit on GitHub, how can I tell what branch it's associated with?

Tags: github

If I'm loking at a commit on GitHub ([for example](https://github.com/vishvananda/novascript/commit/6a8433a2c7b67a1b5740f0aed676b36e6274db88)), how can I tell what branch that commit is associated with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your wish is [their new feature](https://github.com/blog/1451-branch-and-tag-labels-for-commit-pages)

> If the commit is not on the default branch, the indicator will show the branches which contain the commit. If the commit is part of an unmerged pull request, a link will be shown.
>
> Once the commit makes it to the default branch, any tags that contain the commit will be shown, and the default branch will be the only branch listed.

[image]